# Facebook Social Plugin Size

Tags: facebook

I have a standard facebook plugin on my webpage. But though the size is specified, on various occasions (e.g. the PC is not logged in) the text overflows - ignoring the overflow:hidden. In simple words: it does not what it should do. Here goes the code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FKLARTEXT%2F207788969239606%3Fref%3Dhl&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=250&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=30" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; align:"middle"; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:30px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you point us to some specific examples? There were some bugs recently causing social plugins to bleed over their divs. According to the bug tracker these should be fixed by now:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/500201816697073
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/409142149161197

You can always help yourself by putting the social plugin inside another div with overflow:hidden:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:300px;height:100px;">
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="..."/>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, the div around it made it work. Only problem thats left is, that the text varies alot in size - depending if you are logged in or not, or even being not registered. Thanks man!